# Masonry screws won't engage in brick or mortar?

Tags: concrete, screws

I'm trying to put a railing on my back porch but my tapcon masonry screws will not stay in the brick or stay in the mortar. Never catches, just goes in.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right  size drill?

Comment: Any way to modify the bottoms of the posts so they can be placed in a drilled hole and anchored in with expansion cement? I have not seen anything like I suspect you have that are surface mounted. The leverage is just to great for prying out anything that is screwed in, tapcon, expansion bolt or otherwise. Although properly sized and well placed sleeve anchors may do the trick. But with enough force, they will yield too.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you're using the right size drill. If you are then your mortar/brick material might not be suitable for tapcons. As critical as railings are, I'd suggest lag shields and lag bolts. I've always used the stainless steel lag bolts for outdoors but galvanized are available too.

Comment: I agree tapcons are fine for many uses but a hand rail support that has to support 200 lbs force ~ 3’ from the screws sounds like more like a job for “Red heads” a brand  of concrete anchor, sleeved anchors may even be required I would check with the building codes inspector for your area.+